# Launch Center Pro URL-scheme syntax for launching an action

Tags: ios, automation, url

Recently I've been using the Workflow app to create home screen shortcuts that launch third party apps via their respective URL-schemes. This avoids the annoying initial time it takes LCP to load up its home grid on my iPhone 5. However, I've been unable to move one particular third party URL-scheme onto my home screen because it involves an unfortunately necessary lc-callback, and thus needs to be launched from within LCP in order to work. (Lc-callbacks are LCP's special workaround for when an app doesn't support URL chaining via x-callback-url. One has to manually return to LCP from the third party app, but once done the workflow may continue on.)

Does anyone know LCP's own specific URL scheme syntax for launching an action? I've tried things like 'launch://action={{ACTION_NAME}}' but this only opens LCP and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a mix of the [action ID](http://help.contrast.co/hc/en-us/articles/203351237-2-3-Release-Notes) (the name won't work, but every action has its own ID) and the `url` action. It will look like this:

```
launchpro://?url=[action:170]
```

To find the ID, edit an action and scroll to the bottom, you'll find the action there by the edge of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is wondering, for me, as of November '15, Mr. Gruneich's answer, without the 'pro' as in

```
launch://?url=[action:170]
```

works, comes in handy for including *Launch Center Pro* actions in the *Launcher* notification gadget. 
Many thanks for the original answer, trying to figure out the part after '?' was driving me crazy.

Comment: Lucky me, 2015 was upgrade year. The ✨magic✨  of 3D-Touch on the 6s does actually kinda make auxiliary apps like **Launcher** unnecessary. The max four home screen actions **LCP** displays and runs with a single force peek make me happy.  Most of my daily content streams are handled by those four shortcut actions linked to **Editorial** workflows + auxiliary utility apps like **Dropvox** and **Scanbot**. And as **Editorial** releases an update to take advantage of its own icon's force press menu, that'll provide room for actions/workflows to fire off some Python and Bash action on the server

Comment: Down-swipe from top of screen + scroll to __Launcher__ widget + press < one fluid home screen force press and release